# GUI design: disabling labels?

Tags: user-interface, dynamic, ergonomics, ui-design

I couldn't find anything useful on the net to this question:

Is it generally a good idea to disable labels on GUIs (forms etc.) or is it considered a blooper?

I'm not talking about HTML specifically, just any desktop GUI toolkit.

The question is, a label is usually put in front of another GUI element, like a textfield, dropdown box, radio button/s etc. When these input components are being disabled dynamically, that is upon the state of other GUI elements, is it a good idea to also disable its label, even though it provides no means for input itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you should disable (gray out) the label as well as the control. This applies to checkboxes, radio buttons, spin boxes, drop-down menus, etc. This is common practice in Windows and Mac OS.

If you have your controls arranged hierarchically, as you would commonly see in a Settings/Preferences dialog, you should disable all subordinate controls when you disable or deselect a parent control.

An important additional point is that you should also make sure it is obvious to the user *why* an item is disabled. Sometimes, in cases where it's not obvious, it is preferable to allow users to click on non-available controls--rather than disable the controls--then use a dialog or some other method to explain why the control is unavailable.

---

From a programming point of view, you may want to put your control and label into a common container, then disable the container and allow the "enabled" property to cascade downward to the label and control. Most modern frameworks work this way (e.g., WPF, Flex, HTML).

Comment: For whatever reason I have never thought about en/disabling enclosing containers. I've tried it and it works like a charm. The best new piece of knowledge in recent years...